# Detect how many blocks can be moved given a grid of blocks

Tags: java, collision-detection, algorithm

Let G be a grid of booleans where `true` means a block is there and `false` means there isn't a block there.

Let P be the player, which has x and y coordinates and is the size of a block.

G can be accessed with an integer position (ex. (0, 1)) but not with a decimal position (ex. (0.5, 2)). P's position is not guaranteed to be an integer i.e. it could be (1, 1.2) which is in-between 2 blocks.

When the player attempts to move, how do I know the move is possible, and if it isn't possible, how much *can* we move from the specified move?

## Examples

`x = 1, y = 0, G[2, 0] = true`: In this case no move the right is possible, since the player's right side is touching the left side of the block at (2, 0).

`x = -0.4, y = 1, G[1, 2] = true`: Here, moving up is impossible since there is a block directly above the player (y goes up as player goes up). But moving 0.4 blocks to the right is possible, so this should be returned by the algorithm.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a simple matter of rounding/flooring the player position to an integer and checking adjacent indices in G? What have you tried so far and where has it gone wrong?

Comment: @DMGregory Rounding wouldn't work. Example: `x = -0.4` and `G[1] = true`. x would be rounded to `0` and `G[x + 1] = true`. That implies moving 1 block is invalid but it is perfectly valid.

Comment: Why would it imply that? I'd interpret `G[0] == false` and `G[1] == true` to mean that moving past x > 1.0 is invalid, but you'd still have all the room from -0.4 to 1.0 to move, ie. you could conclude that you can move up to 1.4 units rightward before encountering a solid block. (Here I assume that `G[i, j] == true` means there is a block spanning the range `(i <= x < i + 1) && (j <= y <= j+1)`, but it's just a constant offset if you use a different convention)

Comment: Normalize your coordinates to 0..N to avoid your "x = -0.4" rounding math issue.

Comment: @PatrickHughes It would still apply though. Just add 1 to all the coordinates. `x = 0.6, y = 0, G[2, 0] = true, G[round(x) + 1, 0] = true`. Which means the player (which also is 1 block in size) cannot move there. But in reality, there is still 0.4 of a block that can be moved.

Comment: @DMGregory Should've stated that the player is a block wide, so for example if the player is at (0, 0) and there's a block at (1, 0), then the player is touching that block.

Comment: @PatrickHughes Plus, the world is open so there's no "start" that I can anchor to.